# Why sometimes it gives exception but sometimes doesn't?

Tags: java, exception

My program has two parts, one data structure and second operations.

Data Structure part is, basically and object & set of that object. This set is a class that extends ArrayList. Set and Objects are unique, what I mean is if I have a class named A then I have aSet which keeps the all A objects in it.

Operation part is doing some operations on those sets and most of the times it is also creates a new class in the runtime (write the class in a java file and compile it then call it from Reflect library functions e.g. constructor.newInstance(args);) and creates an object from new class then fill inside of it and return it. Since I didn't wanted to overwrite classes I use UUID trimmed for naming the new classes that created at the runtime.

I had noticed something odd. I run my code and it works, then I run it again and at the creation of set, it gives me "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments". I run it again exception, again and again then I run it again then no exception. (Every time it created a new class like I wanted)

So why my code can act like this?

I am using Oracle Java 1.8 on Ubuntu 14.04 with Intellij Idea (tried also Eclipse no change).

**Edit for code:**
"I removed the codes unrelated to the problem"

And this is the part that gives error at my operation; (Initial innerInnerName is the random generated class name)

```
final String outerClassName = "" + initialInnerName + "Table";
final String innerClassName = "" + initialInnerName;

File file = new File("./src/");
URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
URL urls[] = new URL[]{url};
URLClassLoader loader1 = new URLClassLoader(urls);
Class<?> innerClass = loader1.loadClass(innerClassName);

Set<Template> newTable = null;
Class<?> outerClass = loader1.loadClass(outerClassName);
Constructor<?> constructorOfOuterClass = outerClass.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
Object[] objArg = {innerClass,10};
newTable = (Set<Template>) constructorOfOuterClass.newInstance(objArg);
```

**Edit 2**

Exception being thrown at last line of last code which is:

```
newTable = (Set<Template>) constructorOfOuterClass.newInstance(objArg);
```

Well I had tried to do MCVE as much as possible.

Comment: We'll need to see the code in order to help.

Comment: @KevinW. two problems, I am not sure I am at the liberty of sharing all of the code, second code is kind of long so is it ok, If I added the parts that related to this only?

Comment: Don't show the whole code, and don't show chunks out of context that don't run. Make a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: 1.) If you're not sure you can share some of the code, you may need to look somewhere else;
2.) Don't add all of the code, create a MCVE as linked in the above comment

Comment: The downvotes are an indication to you that you have indeed done something that the community doesn't like. In this case, as in most, there are comments that explain the problem(s). Thank you for making the effort to make this a better question. Edits that make a question better frequently improve the votes that the question gets, though downvoters don't necessarily know that the question was edited.

Comment: One thing that still isn't clear: where _exactly_ is the exception being thrown? Which line, specifically?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom I understand that I may have asked wrongly. I am not frequent user of StackOverflow or not a very good programmer yet. However, without telling me what to fix downvoting doesn't seem to fair. If I made something wrong and you asked me to fix it and I didn't then I understand the downvotes. This is not the first time, I had asked a question last month again a lot of downvotes. Did I insult somebody? No. Did I do something offending no? I just didn't even know how to ask that what I know. That's why I asked at here because I didn't even know what to write to Google.

Comment: Ok, I understand your frustration. For the record, I have not voted either up or down on this question. I'm waiting to see how it shapes up. That said, SO makes its standards quite clear. There is advice given when one signs up, there is the help center, and there are lots of examples of good questions (those with upvotes) and bad (those with downvotes). It can be frustrating to deal with the large number of questions that don't provide enough info and yet want answers. But I've never seen a downvoted question that didn't have plenty of guidance given. You did well and improved the question.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom thanks, I am trying to read the examples of good questions but sometimes it is so hard to ask in that way. Example; Last time I had asked I was wondering that can I change the code I am running in the runtime and I said "Like I want to be able to get a string input that will change my running code like a mathematic function input", for some reason people didn't like it and I got downvoted. I appreciate your help about pointing my mistakes. I wish the community where more like you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "Outer Class" has two constructors, one that takes one argument and one that takes two. When you go to instantiate the outer class, you get the first in the list of constructors:

```
Constructor<?> constructorOfOuterClass = outerClass.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
```

and then you try to invoke it with two arguments:

```
Object[] objArg = {innerClass,10};
newTable = (Set<Template>) constructorOfOuterClass.newInstance(objArg);
```

The problem is that the constructors aren't necessarily in the order you expect. No particular order is guaranteed, so sometimes you will get the one argument constructor and sometimes the two argument constructor. When you get the two argument constructor, all is well. But when you get the one argument constructor and invoke it with two arguments, well, you know all too well what happens then.

You need to determine which of the constructors is the one you want, and select it, rather than assuming that it is the first one in the list.

Comment: Oh, ok so what you are saying when I take the constructors in ".getDeclaredConstructors()" it doesn't give it in the written order of java file?

Comment: Correct. It gives them to you in an undefined order.

Comment: Thanks, a lot. This will help me a lot.

Comment: So I change it to this, http://pastebin.com/KvVyicyG
I think this will be fine right? Thanks. I tried this in a for loop (1000 tries) and no exception.